# Closing JavaFX tabs doesn't release memory from ArrayLists and TableViews in that tab

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, javafx

I've been trying to figure out why a JavaFX based application I am working on uses up so much memory.  I noticed memory went up each time I opened a new tab in the application, and wasn't being GC after I had closed the tab.  I would keep opening and closing tabs until eventually it ran out of memory and crashed.

So I wrote and tried a very simple program and GUI.  The code is below.  What I found was that if I set the items in the TableView to null, cleared out the ArrayList, and instantiated a new ArrayList of the same variable name, only then it would GC.

Is this normal behavior for Java and/or JavaFX?  Normal in that it won't "destroy" those objects in a tab once the tab is closed?  Bug with Java 8/FX?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TabTest extends Application {

    ArrayList<String> _list;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        SplitPane split = new SplitPane();
        split.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);     
        HBox window = new HBox();       
        HBox top = new HBox(20);
        HBox bottom = new HBox(20);
        Group group = new Group();
        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        Button btn = new Button("Create Tab");
        top.getChildren().add(btn);
        bottom.getChildren().add(tabPane);
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {            
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                createTabAndList(tabPane);
            }
        });
        split.getItems().addAll(top,bottom);
        window.getChildren().add(split);
        group.getChildren().add(window);
        Scene scene = new Scene(group);
        split.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());
        split.prefHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());        
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void createTabAndList(TabPane tabPane){
        _list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++){
            _list.add("Test Test Test");
        }
        TableView<String> tb1 = new TableView<String>();
        tb1.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(_list));
        Tab tab = new Tab("Tab1");
        tab.setContent(tb1);
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);
        tabPane.setTabClosingPolicy(TabPane.TabClosingPolicy.SELECTED_TAB);        
        tab.setOnClosed(new EventHandler<Event>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Event arg0) {
                tb1.setItems(null);
                _list.clear();
                _list = new ArrayList<String>();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: As a rule, Java doesn't destroy *anything* that you still have a reference to.

Comment: Why would I/the app have a reference to it if the tab is closed?

Comment: Because whether a GUI element is visually accessible or not doesn't have anything to do with the objects that make it. What if you wanted to implement an "undo close tab", for example?

Comment: @RealSkeptic But in the posted example, once the tab is closed, it is no longer in the tab pane's `getTabs()` list. Furthermore, the client code shown maintains no reference to it. Thus if the `tabPane` still retains a reference, that would be a memory leak (or really an unintentionally retained reference bug), since there would be no public API way to remove that reference. (If you wanted to implement an "undo close tab", you would need to retain a reference to the closed tab specifically for that purpose: this code doesn't do that.)

Comment: @RealSkeptic The code is complete apart from imports (which would be nice). `launch(...)` creates an instance for you and executes `start(...)`.

Comment: It's not compiling. Complains that `list` has to be final or effectively final. So unless this is another thing I missed, the real `list` is not a local variable.

Comment: Yes sorry, I didn't mean to move the list to a local variable.  Edited the question to fix that and include imports.

Comment: Well, this version seems to be garbage-collecting quite well when I comment out the `setOnClosed` part. I limited my heap to 1024m, it takes about 18 tabs to go out of memory, but if I create and delete, create and delete tabs, I can create a lot more than 18 (provided I delete them), I never hit an OOM, and printing the free and total memory shows that garbage is being collected.

Comment: @RealSkeptic With it commented out:  When I open five tabs, close them, then run GC, Old Gen goes down to ~112 MB.  When left uncommented and do the same thing, Old Gen goes down to ~7 MB.  That is the difference I am describing with this question.

Comment: But you do have one copy of the list still hanging around (because `_list` is a live reference) when you comment it out. So of course it will not be GC'ed. What happens if you open five tabs, close them, open five tabs, close them, etc. several times, and then GC and check? Different results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I played with your sample a bit, out of curiosity. I worked on jdk1.8.60 on on Ubuntu. First, there is the global *_list* field, this remains in the memory forever, naturally, unless you specifically clean it. To simplify the things, I made the *_list* local. Then I removed the onClosed handler to see what happens. So the method *createTabAndList* was like this:

```
public void createTabAndList(TabPane tabPane){
    List<String> _list = new ArrayList<String>(); //_list is local now
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++){
        _list.add("Test Test Test");
    }
    TableView<String> tb1 = new TableView<String>();
    tb1.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(_list));
    Tab tab = new Tab("Tab1");
    tab.setContent(tb1);
    tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);
    tabPane.setTabClosingPolicy(TabPane.TabClosingPolicy.SELECTED_TAB);        
    //tab.setOnClosed(new EventHandler<Event>() {
    //    @Override
    //    public void handle(Event arg0) {
    //        tb1.setItems(null);
    //        _list.clear();
    //        _list = new ArrayList<String>();
    //    }
    //});
}
```

1. Newly started app consumes 8MB.
2. 1 tab created - 63 MB
3. 10 tabs created - 560 MB - there are 10 instances of the list now
4. All 10 tabs closed - 62 MB

Indeed, JavaFX seems to keep the reference to the last active tab, including its content. There was non of your code on the reference path in hepdump, it was all in the JFX internals. I noticed it several times (tables, css processor), that JFX caches a lot of stuff that is not needed any more. But it gets typically cleaned up when after some time, or when the memory gets scarce. When I created and closed the 10 tabs several times again, it never consumed more that these 62 MB.

So, the answer is

- Indeed, JFX remembers some extra stuff, but within reasonable limits. The memory does not grow infinitely by repeated opening and closing the tab.
- If you really need such huge data models in the memory, like in your example (10M rows), then it makes sense to clear the tab on closing.

Comment: Yes update 60 seemed to clear up a lot of memory problems I had been having.